# Date selection for week-to-date

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I have a comboBox `DateType` with options `Today, Yesterday, Week-to-date and Manual Entry`.
I also have 2 textboxes - one for `Start Date` and one for `End Date`.
By default, the `DateType` will be set to `Today`'s date.

For eg.: Let's say, current date is 01/11/2011 (Tues)

```
When DateType : Today
Start Date = 01/11/2011
End Date = 01/11/2011

When DateType : Week-to-date (Note: Each week will be `Sun to Sat`)
Start Date = 01/09/2012 (Sun)
End Date = 01/11/2012 (Current Date)
```

Few Variables:

```
var startDate = new Date(document.getElementsByName('Start Date').value);
var endDate = new Date(document.getElementsByName('End Date').value);
```

I am new to javascript, so could anyone help me frame a function that can modify the `Start Date` and `End Date` based on the DateType selected(as above). 
I need the condition only for `Week-to-date`
The rest would be similar,I guess, so I can frame the remaining conditions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put some html and whatever functions you have so far on JSFiddle.net then we can look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the onchange event of the select control you can set a date range something like:

```
function setDateRange()  
{  
  var periodSelection = dateseln.period.options[dateseln.period.selectedIndex].value;  
  var start;
  switch (periodSelection)  
  {  
    case "Today":  
      start = new Date();  
      break;  
    case "WeekToDate":  
      start = new Date();  
      start.setDate(start.getDate() - start.getDay());  
      break;  
  }  
  dateseln.startDate.value = start;  
  dateseln.endDate.value = new Date();
}
```